# PHP Separating Contents from While Loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

Okay so my code below echoes out two URLs from the database but I want to have the ability to separate the two and update the row where the image is clicked.  Example: Two images are output, users clicks image on the left, MySQL knows which row to update depending on which image they clicked.  Depending on the image they click it will update the image's votes in MySQL.  Ideally I want the "vote-ups" to show in place of the 112 and 156 accordingly from the database.

Let me rephrase to clarify: my code echoes out two images selected from the database.  The code should tell you that if you read it.  From there, I want to be able to separate the two images so I can do a query to update the specific row with that image and update the total votes that image has from `votes` to `votes`+1.  I tried doing this but it would update both row's votes by 1.

How can I do this?

```
<?php
    include_once('db.php');

    $selectURLSQL = "SELECT * FROM `urls` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";
    $selectURLQuery = mysql_query($selectURLSQL);
    $URL_Row = mysql_fetch_array($selectURLQuery);
?>

<?php
    while($URL_Row = mysql_fetch_array($selectURLQuery)) {
?>

<img class="img" name="img" src="<?php echo $URL_Row['url']; ?>" style="height:400px;width: 260px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<?php 
    } 
?>
<br /><br />
<span style="font-size:18px;font-family:trebuchet ms;">156 Vote-Ups</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
<small>Vs.</small>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: trebuchet ms;">112 Vote-Ups</span><br /><br />
```

Comment: All `mysql_*` functions are [**officially deprecated**](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp) *(no longer supported/maintained)* and will be [**removed**](http://j.mp/11j2t6j) in the future. You should update your code using [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure future functionality.

Comment: Thanks that was very unhelpful.  I know mysql_ is deprecated but I haven't made the switch.  So can you help or not?  Sheesh...

Comment: This question makes almost no sense, please make an effort to improve it and add relevant details so you can get a proper answer.

Comment: Let me rephrase for you: my code echoes out two images selected from the database.  The code should tell you that if you read it.  From there, I want to be able to separate the two images so I can do a query to update the specific row with that image and update the total votes that image has from `votes` to `votes`+1.  I tried doing this but it would update both row's votes by 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say your table `urls` is structured like this:

```
id  |  url  |  rank
```

you have to increment the `rank` column for each click on the image corresponding to the url.

my idea is to create a link around the image, and this link will contain the `id` of the image so it can be passed in the URL like this `?id=xxx`

if you want to show the votes outside the loop, you can save them temporarily in an `array`

Your Code:

```
<?php 
    include_once('db.php');

    $selectURLSQL = "select * from urls ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2";
    $selectURLQuery = mysql_query($selectURLSQL);

    if (isset($_GET['id'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $sql = "UPDATE urls set rank = rank+1 WHERE id = $id";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }

    $i = 0;
    $votes = array();
    while ($URL_Row = mysql_fetch_array($selectURLQuery)):
        $votes[$i++] = $URL_Row['rank'];
    ?>
        <a href="?id=<?php echo $URL_Row['id']; ?>">
            <img class="img" name="img" src="<?php echo $URL_Row['url']; ?>" style="height:400px;width: 260px;">
        </a>
    <?php endwhile; ?>


<br /><br />
<span style="font-size:18px;font-family:trebuchet ms;"><?php echo $votes[0]; ?> Vote-Ups</span>
<small>Vs.</small>
<span style="font-size: 18px; font-family: trebuchet ms;"><?php echo $votes[1]; ?> Vote-Ups</span><br /><br />
```

Comment: Be more clear next time please!

Now use the vote-up system of Stack Overflow to vote-up the response if it's useful :p